# Fix Overlapping Nested Div Elements

Tags: css, reactjs, overlapping, comboboxmodel

I am creating a data table grid in react, currently I am able to render my dummy data with my code.  But the problem is that the header row is overlapped by the first data row, which is very annoying

This is the markup I have :

```
<div class='Table_table'>
   <div class='Table_table-header'>
        <div style="height:30px;">
           <div class='table_fixed-cols'>
           </div>
           <div class='Table_x-scroll header'>
               <div class='table_row'>
                   <div class="table_cell"> Name </div>
                   <div class="table_cell"> Age </div>
                   <div class="table_cell"> Location </div>
               </div>
           </div>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class='table-container'>
            <div class="table_fixed-cols">
                <div class="table_row even"><div>
                <div class="table_row even"><div>
                <div class="table_row even"><div>
            </div>
            <div class="table_x-scroll">
                <div class="table_row even">Dana</div>
                <div class="table_row ">57</div>
                <div class="table_row even">San Francisco</div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS I have:

```
.Table__table{
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.table__cell{
    border-right: 1px solid black !important;
    padding: 3px 5px !important;
    position: absolute;
}

.table__row{
    display: flex !important;
    position: absolute!important;
    margin-top: 1%;
    left: 0 !important;
    /* overflow: auto!important; */
}

.table_fixed-cols{
    top:0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    z-index: 100 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    position: absolute !important;
}

.table_x-scroll{
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

The thing is that I see my first data row completely overlapped with the header row ( class='Table_table-header' ).

Have been spending hours on trying to fix this issue now..

Any help would be much appreciated !

change css for container switch between position: absolute, position: relative[image: issue]

Comment: Is this correct CSS code?
Case .table__cell in CSS have two _ and in HTML code it's set as .table_cell with one _

Comment: Also added your code for testing in sandox https://codesandbox.io/s/static-r37uu?fontsize=14 and assume that you could add not all styles you are using

Comment: Hi,  thanks for checking it out for me.  Yes, it is exactly the same problem I am seeing here, still have no clue what caused it